# Verbs for Martial Arts, Dance, and Performances

Tags: verbs, sports

My students keep writing "I play kendo", "He plays diving", "they play ballet", etc. I've been correcting them to use "do"/"does", but are there other better verbs? I've considered using "practice" and "compete in", but each tends to exclude the other.

Comment: You have to say in your question "why" you have rejected *practice* and *compete in*, although the second justification isn 't really needed.

Comment: Generally, (with some exceptions) we use the verb form in this context: "I dive," "I dance," "I act," in the sense of one's profession/ vocation/ avocation. The *do* form is awkward and doesn't sound good in formal speech or writing. Of course, it's getting popular in AmE: "I do (any noun)."  It's a thought-provoking question, though. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well while there are other words you could use 'I practice Kendo', 'I do/go diving', or even 'I AM a kendoshi' or 'I AM a diver', however to most native English speakers do/does would be more common and more natural. All are correct and fine, however.