# Are there any rules for which verbs should be used when talking about sports?

Tags: grammar

For a lot of sports such as tennis, basketball etc., the verb *play* can be used. When it comes to other sports such as judo, powerlifting or even swimming using the verb play feels a little strange to me.

In this case, what do you think the most suitable word to use would be and is there a specific reason why the word *play* just doesn't seem to fit?

Comment: The best auxiliary verb for *which* sport? Different sports might pair better with some verbs that others sports don't—as you've already noted. Also, I'm not sure if asking what the *most appropriate is* can have an objective answer. It's also not clear that there has be be an auxiliary verb in the first place. It's actually *tennis* that would seem to be the exception. *Tennis* is not a verb. We can't say *we* ***tennis***, but have to say *we **play** tennis*. However, that's not required with *swim*, which is a verb. We just say *we* ***swim***. Why put anything in front of it?

Comment: From what you've said it seems that is just a matter of dining which auxiliary verb goes with each sport, rather than there being any rules that can be applied.

Comment: Just curious -- why are we calling these verbs _auxiliary_ verbs?

Comment: Exercise. Work out.

Comment: @JasonBassford *Yesterday we **went swimming**, it was the first time since the lockdown was lifted in Italy.* I see nothing wrong using "go" with "swimming"

Comment: @Woodland tennis, basketball, yoga, football, kickbox etc... are not *verbs*, you don't say "We basketballed last night" although it's perfectly understandable, and I'm pretty certain that some American speakers will find this sentence grammatical and proper, so that's why we need a **verb** (not an auxiliary) e.g. We **played** basketball last night. They are **doing** gymnastics at this moment,  She used **to go** swimming in the lake etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't see anything wrong with *we* ***went swimming*** either. But it's not necessary in the same way that *play* is necessary when paired with *tennis*. (The equivalent is simply *we* ***swam***.) You make the same point I was trying to in your next comment: we don't say *we* ***basketballed***.)

Comment: @IsabelArcher I'm using *auxiliary* descriptively in the sense of " offering or providing help". It's a verb that's not needed to be there when paired with *swim*, which is its own verb. If the noun form of *swim*, for instance, is used, then it's actually a noun, and what comes before the noun is actually just a verb. So, it's not, strictly speaking, an *auxiliary verb* in the normal sense where you have one verb before another actual verb. But it is still acting in an auxiliary capacity to the verb that is, in this case, taking a noun role instead of its normal verb role.

Comment: @IsabelArcher In hindsight, perhaps I should have referred to it as a *"subsidiary verb"* so as to avoid confusion with the regular compound term …

Comment: Thanks, @JasonBassford! I asked, because while I'm very familiar with the generally used grammatical terms, I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge of the more specialized terms that I'm discovering on this site. I thought I might have missed something here, so thank you very much for explaining the choice of term.

Comment: Related: ['playing sports': does swimming count](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392338/playing-sports-does-swimming-count) // [verbs for martial arts, dance, and performances](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361250/verbs-for-martial-arts-dance-and-performances).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three verbs which can be used with sports: **play**, **go** and **do**.

According to https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/play-go-do,

> ### Play
>
> Play is used with sports that have **teams, rules and competitions**:
>
> Badminton, baseball, football, golf, rugby and tennis are some examples.
>
> *I have been playing tennis for over ten years.*
>
> *When I was young we played football just outside our house in the street.*
>
> ### Go
>
> Go is used with activities where the activity is in the **-ing form**.
>
> To camp – go camping
>
> *We went camping by the lake last summer.*
>
> Other activities that take 'go' are: dancing, jogging, running, hiking, riding, swimming, cycling, climbing etc.
>
> ### Do
>
> For **all other recreational activities** we use do. Aerobics, athletics, gymnastics, judo, karate and yoga are some examples.
>
> *All young children should be encouraged to do gymnastics.*
>
> *Sarah does yoga with some of her friends.*

Also, please note that using **go** implies that it is neccessary to travel somewhere (or... well, literally to go somewhere) in order to start doing mentioned sport, but you would actually **do** sports ending on **-ing** if you're already at the gym or some facility (pool, climbing gym, etc). Please compare:

> *I would like to go powerlifting tomorrow.*
>
> *I often do powerlifting at the California State University gym.*

As a result, use **do** with judo. And the reason **play** doesn't fit is that it's used, again, with sports that have teams, rules and competitions (i.e. games - football is a game, volleyball is a game, hockey is a game, chess is also a game, although it usually involves only two players, and so on). Hope that helps!

P.S. As it was said in comments, you can use swim without anything, because it is a verb that can stand alone:

> *Rebecca swims fastest in our class.*
>
> *I used to swim often when I was 12*.
>
> *I swam five kilometers*.

Comment: Whoah.. You got me uncovered, I sincerely apologize. I'll edit the answer right now. And thanks for your comment, by the way!

Comment: Done. Sorry for improper terminology usage. The only thing I can say as an excuse is that I am a newcomer into English linguistics...

Comment: If the answer is correct, and perfecty supported but the terminolgy is wrong, someone will downvote for that very reason. Revise the most common grammatical terms, and you'll be OK. Welcome to EL&U :)

Comment: I definitely will revise the most common grammatical terms in order not to make such mistakes in the future. Thank you very much for pointing out the mistakes without being harsh or mean!